# LDAP Query to get users that have same value in two attributes

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have to find all the users that have same value in "cn" and "uid".
How can I create the correct ldap query ?

Bye

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can do this using a single LDAP search filter.  A filter expression is made up of name-value predicates - attribute types on the left side, patterns on the right side.  You'll have to read all entries and compare cn to uid on the client side.